# nleqslv performance for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have benefited a lot from **data.table**'s high performance in large data analysis. However, recently I noticed that **nleqslv** in **data.table** is not as efficient as in **data.frame**. Not sure if it is because of the way I use it. Here is the example.

```
library(nleqslv)
library(data.table)
s<-1000
# data.frame
df<-data.frame(pd=rbeta(s,2.5,15),ce=runif(s,0,1))
fn_df<-function(x){ sum(pnorm(qnorm(df[,'pd'])-z*x)*df[,'ce'])-50}

# data.table
dt<-as.data.table(df)
fn_dt<-function(x){ sum(pnorm(qnorm(dt[,pd])-z*x)*dt[,ce])-50}

z<-rnorm(s)
system.time(df_ob<-nleqslv(1,fn_df))
system.time(dt_ob<-nleqslv(1,fn_dt))


> system.time(df_ob<-nleqslv(1,fn_df))
user  system elapsed 
0.032   0.000   0.033
> system.time(dt_ob<-nleqslv(1,fn_dt))
user  system elapsed 
0.092   0.000   0.089
```

The results indicates **nleqslv** runs much slower in **data.table**. I wonder if there is a way to make **nleqslv** run faster in **data.table**, or at least as fast as in **data.frame**.

Comment: Just want to point out that the time difference is not significant for this case (both are less than 0.1 second). However, a large number simulation of calling this function will make it a high cost.

Comment: I am the author of `nleqslv`.  I find your result very strange since data.table is reputed to be a lot quicker than dataframe. I have  run `nleqslv` with argument `control=list(trace=1)` once for your two cases to see what might be going on. In both cases `nleqslv` reports `No better point found` ==> NO SOLUTION. My advice is to make your example reproducible by adding the necessary `library(...)` calls and first running `nleqslv` once so that you can check if it has found a solution before doing any timing. You should always check first by displaying the result of `nleqslv`.

Comment: Additional remark, You don't need the argument `control=list(trace=1)` to find out if a solution was obtained.

Comment: Thanks, Bhas. I have added the library in the code. I am sorry I used a bad example for illustration. I think the issue is not about the efficiency or robustness of nleqslv, but rather about how data.table implementation in selecting columns. Sorry for the misleading title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task here is just subsetting columns. There is no real advantage of using data.tables in comparison to data.frames or lists, if that's all you do. Agreeably, it could perform at least as fast as data.frames, but `[.data.table` does a lot more than `[.data.frame` (just have a look at both these functions) and that adds a slight overhead, which is noticeable when accessed repeatedly.

It is extremely important to understand that data.tables don't make everything you use them with faster. You've to understand and use it correctly. For example, `DT[, j]` returns a *copy* of the columns subsetted. This is because of data.table's reference semantics -- else updating one data.table by reference would also affect another.

Therefore, in your example, using `$` or `[[`, since you subset a single column would be much better, since it doesn't use `[.data.table`:

```
system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) df[, 'pd'])
system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) dt[, pd])

system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) df$pd) 
system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) dt$pd)

system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) df[['pd']])
system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) dt[['pd']])

#       Code      Time (sec)
# df[, 'pd']           0.008
#   dt[, pd]           0.303
#      df$pd           0.008
#      dt$pd           0.007
# df[['pd']]           0.008
# dt[['pd']]           0.006
```

Similarly, if you'd like to subset more than one column repeatedly, then `as.list(dt)[cols]` would be more efficient. `data.table` is not designed with / optimised for repeated subsetting of columns type operations in mind (although the copying part could be addressed when `shallow()` will be exported).

If you're performing this operation a lot, even more than `data.frames`, having them as `lists` would make its even more efficient as `list` is a primitive type, and doesn't have the overhead of `[.data.frame` even.

```
ll = as.list(df)
system.time(for (i in 1:1e3) ll[['pd']])
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, Arun. You are definitely right. I used $ in both data.table and data.frame following your suggestion, and now the run time are the same. One thing that still bothers me is that when using 
    "qnorm(dt[,'pd',with=F)"
I got the following error
    "Error in qnorm(dt[, j = "pd", with = F]) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function". 
Do you happen to know why? Thanks

Comment: Never mind, Arun. I think the reason is that "dt[, j = "pd", with = F]" is a list, an unlist function solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comments `nleqslv` can't find a solution for your problem.
You should check if your function has a solution =0.

Try this:

```
s<-1000
# data.frame
df<-data.frame(pd=rbeta(s,2.5,15),ce=runif(s,0,1))
fn_df<-function(x){ sum(pnorm(qnorm(df[,'pd'])-z*x)*df[,'ce'])-50}

z<-rnorm(s)

fn_df(0)
fv <- Vectorize(fn_df,"x")
curve(fv,from=-10,to=10)
```

and the plot made by `curve` clearly reveals that the minimum for function `fn_df` lies at or near 0 with `fn_df(0) = 21.2253`. So your function `fn_df` has **no solution** for `fn_df(x)=0`.

If the `50` in your function is changed to `90` the minimum of your function still lies at or near 0 with `fn_df(0) = -19.65275` implying that there is solution for `fn_df(x) = 0`. Like this

```
fn_df<-function(x){ sum(pnorm(qnorm(df[,'pd'])-z*x)*df[,'ce'])-90}
```

Lets now investigate solving your equation.
Your function has a single scalar argument so you could try `uniroot`.
Like this

```
uniroot(fn_df, c(-.5,5))
```

with this output (with blank lines removed to conserve space):

```
$root
[1] 0.7711256
$f.root
[1] -3.789903e-05
$iter
[1] 8
$init.it
[1] NA
$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

The difficulty in your case is to find an appropriate range for `x` such that the function value at both endpoints differ in sign.

So you could try `nleqslv` like this

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(1,fn_df)
```

with this result (again empty lines in output removed to conserve space)

```
$x
[1] 0.7711265
$fvec
[1] 3.268497e-12
$termcd
[1] 1
$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"
$scalex
[1] 1
$nfcnt
[1] 4
$njcnt
[1] 1
$iter
[1] 4
```

The solution found by `uniroot` and `nleqslv` are very close  to each other.

Finally it is **not** `nleqslv` that is slow in your example but the way you are working with `data.table`. I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks again, Bhas. I have no doubt about the robustness of nleqslv. Sorry again for using a bad example and a misleading subtitle.

Comment: @Loy. My answer was intended to urge you to check your function(s) for solvability and to test the return code/value of nleqslv before doing any timings or drawing conclusions.

Comment: Thanks, Bhas. I'll keep it in mind next time. The motivation behind this post is actually a real problem from work, in which the solvability of the function is not an issue. To illustrate the problem, I made up a simple example, which turns out to be a bad one. As you mentioned, it has more to do with how I use data.table rather than nleqslv. Once again, I apologize for using the misleading title "nleqslv performance for data.table" which sounds like an nleqslv performance issue, but in fact it has nothing to do with it.